# Every infinite G has a S.T $o(a)=\infty?$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, infinite-groups

Is it true to claim that for every **infinite** Group G then there is a in G such that $o(a)=\infty?$

I took few examples and this sound correct, but any ideas on how can I prove this in general?

Comment: An advice if you want to prove some property (but aren't sure it holds) it to also try to prove its negation. Which here is quite easy to establish.

Comment: A brief discussion of your "few examples" and what you see in them would improve your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true.

For a counterexample, the direct sum of infinitely many cyclic groups of order $2$ is an infinite group, but every element of that group has order 2.

One could restrict the question the way that [Burnside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem) restricted it in the early 20th century: if a group $G$ is infinite and finitely generated, does it have an element of infinite order? Even that turns out to be false but it was much harder to find a counterexample. You can read about  counterexamples in that link.